# Не передается значение с viewmodel на action контроллера в asp.net core

Tags: c#, action, asp-net-core-mvc

Не удается передать список элементов **Allrooms** в action контроллера при нажатии на кнопку **Обновить**.

Здесь **model.Allrooms** пусто [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditSelectedRooms(EditSelectedRoomsViewModel model)
        {
            foreach (var id in model.Allrooms)
            {
                var room = dBContext.Rooms.Find(id);
                room.ClassName = model.ClassName;
                dBContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

А в **input** значения передаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@model Hotel.ViewModel.EditSelectedRoomsViewModel

<form asp-action="EditSelectedRooms" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ClassName" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="ClassName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Allrooms" value="@Model.Allrooms" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Обновить" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было использовать `for` и заменить `input`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Allrooms.Count(); i++)
{
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Allrooms[i]" value="@Model.Allrooms[i]" />
}
```